# How do I save changes back to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a database in my c# project, and I have got a little problem with it.  I can read the data from the database and show it, but when I am using an SQL query like insert/update/remove, the changes does not save back into the database file and after a few minutes they just gone...

A little code example :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string sql_string = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
string sql = "INSERT INTO Table1 (name, time, needs, text) VALUES ('string', 'string', 'string', 'string')";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sql_string);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(ds); ;
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         
conn.Close();
```

Now I understand that I need to use the SqlDataAdapter.update() to save the changes, but I don't know how to use it?

Comment: are you sure you are posting all the code related to your question?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **DataSet**, after you populate your **DataSet** from database, you have to propagate these changes back to update your database. **DataSet** is a run-time object stored in memory.

If you're simply executing a SQL commend to update your database, then it's straightforward (use `using statement` and `Parameters.Add` instead of placing values directly to your SQL statement to avoid injection):

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
{
    string sqlStr = @"INSERT INTO FooTable (FooName) VALUES (@FooName)";
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sqlStr, conn))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FooName", 'someString');

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks,
and is all the code...
but the problem is that the code runs fine and after i close the program and check the database for changes i don't see any

Comment: @guy, have you check your database for changes before closing the program (during run-time)? If so, are you changing your DataSet and forget to propagate changes back to your DataBase?

Comment: i checked during run time and after closing the program...
and there was no change...
but the thing is, that if i run the program again (after runing the code above )
and ask the progrem to show all the data from the database, i see the changes from the last run time even though the changes were not saved in the database.
but if i exit the visual studio and open it again and run the program ,and ask it to show all the data from the database
i dont see the changes...like thire were only temporary or something.
any ideas ?

Comment: @guy, I think I see the problem. Restarting VS will clean your project. Instead of restarting VS, if you go to "Build > Clean Solution" and "Start Debugging" to compile your project again, you should see no change as well. If this is what happen, you are not making changes to your DataBase, you are only making changes to DataSet. Are you sure you are posting all the code? Also, add conn.Dispose() if you are not using using-statement.

Comment: thanks,
so if this is not how i change the database  
how do i change it ?

Comment: Using SQLite I create a `transaction` with `SQLiteTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction()` before executing the query. Just before closing the connection I run a `trans.Commit()`. Without that the changes are not saved to the db.

Answer (score 1):

I'm digging up this question because the correct answer is not clearly described (please read the whole thread if you disagree): the closest to being correct is actually from jfuhr.

I have experienced the identical problem to the one first described by the OP, i.e.:

- Can connect to the DB
- Can retrieve all records (or subset) from the DB
- *Appear* to be able to write changes to the DB (and even use a separate datagridview control which retrieves all records from the DB including the ones you've added/edited to confirm this)
- However the changes are not propagated to the DB somehow - a restart of the whole IDE (or inspection via SQL Server Management Studio) shows the new records have not been saved.

In my case this problem occurred despite using proven code samples which worked perfectly elsewhere.

The solution is to change the path in the connection string from:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|...Database.mdf
```

to the absolute path:

```
AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Me\\Projects\\MyProject\\MyDatabase.mdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look on this [article](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UpdatetableusingSqlDataAdapter.htm) its give a good example on how to use SqlDataAdapter to select and update data.

Answer (score 0):

KMC's code should update your table.

The only thing I can think of is that in your connection string, you have
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;

But it looks like you are connecting to a SQLExpress instance.  Try removing this and from the conn string.  When the ExecuteNonQuery is called, the changes are immediate.